# Vagrantcloud packer upload error

Tags: vagrant, packer

I get the error

> virtualbox-iso: Running post-processor: vagrant-cloud
>   ==> virtualbox-iso (vagrant-cloud): Verifying box is accessible: redacted/ubuntu2004
>   Build 'virtualbox-iso' errored: 1 error(s) occurred:
>   * Post-processor failed: Error retrieving box: Resource not found!

This is [my JSON file (pastebin link or below)](https://pastebin.com/VqZp68JC):

```
{
  "variables": {
    "cloud_token": "{{ env `VAGRANT_CLOUD_TOKEN` }}",
    "version": "4.0.0"
  },
  "provisioners": [
    {
      "type": "shell",
      "execute_command": "echo 'vagrant' | {{.Vars}} sudo -S -E bash '{{.Path}}'",
      "script": "scripts/ansible.sh"
    },
    {
      "type": "shell",
      "execute_command": "echo 'vagrant' | {{.Vars}} sudo -S -E bash '{{.Path}}'",
      "script": "scripts/setup.sh"
    },
    {
      "type": "ansible-local",
      "playbook_file": "../shared/main.yml",
      "galaxy_file": "../shared/requirements.yml"
    },
    {
      "type": "shell",
      "execute_command": "echo 'vagrant' | {{.Vars}} sudo -S -E bash '{{.Path}}'",
      "script": "scripts/cleanup.sh"
    }
  ],
  "builders": [
    {
      "type": "virtualbox-iso",
      "boot_command": [
        "<esc><wait>",
        "<esc><wait>",
        "<enter><wait>",
        "/install/vmlinuz",
        " auto=true",
        " url=http://{{ .HTTPIP }}:{{ .HTTPPort }}/preseed.cfg",
        " locale=en_US<wait>",
        " console-setup/ask_detect=false<wait>",
        " console-setup/layoutcode=us<wait>",
        " console-setup/modelcode=pc105<wait>",
        " debconf/frontend=noninteractive<wait>",
        " debian-installer=en_US<wait>",
        " fb=false<wait>",
        " initrd=/install/initrd.gz<wait>",
        " kbd-chooser/method=us<wait>",
        " keyboard-configuration/layout=USA<wait>",
        " keyboard-configuration/variant=USA<wait>",
        " netcfg/get_domain=vm<wait>",
        " netcfg/get_hostname=vagrant<wait>",
        " grub-installer/bootdev=/dev/sda<wait>",
        " noapic<wait>",
        " -- <wait>",
        "<enter><wait>"
      ],
      "boot_wait": "10s",
      "disk_size": 81920,
      "guest_os_type": "Ubuntu_64",
      "headless": false,
      "http_directory": "http",
      "iso_urls": [
        "iso/focal-legacy-server-amd64.iso",
        "http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-legacy-server/releases/20.04/release/ubuntu-20.04-legacy-server-amd64.iso"
      ],
      "iso_checksum_type": "sha256",
      "iso_checksum": "36f15879bd9dfd061cd588620a164a82972663fdd148cce1f70d57d314c21b73",
      "ssh_username": "vagrant",
      "ssh_password": "vagrant",
      "ssh_port": 22,
      "ssh_wait_timeout": "1800s",
      "shutdown_command": "echo 'vagrant'|sudo -S shutdown -P now",
      "guest_additions_path": "VBoxGuestAdditions_{{.Version}}.iso",
      "virtualbox_version_file": ".vbox_version",
      "vm_name": "packer-ubuntu-20.04-amd64",
      "vboxmanage": [
        [
          "modifyvm",
          "{{.Name}}",
          "--memory",
          "2048"
        ],
        [
          "modifyvm",
          "{{.Name}}",
          "--cpus",
          "2"
        ]
      ]
    }
  ],
  "post-processors": [
    [
      {
        "type": "vagrant",
        "output": "builds/{{.Provider}}-ubuntu2004.box"

      },
      {
        "type": "vagrant-cloud",
        "box_tag": "redacted/ubuntu2004",
        "access_token": "{{user `cloud_token`}}",
        "version": "{{user `version`}}"
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You first have to create the box on app.vagrantup.com. Make sure the name matches what you gave in the HCL file.